# Could not keep landscape in iPad iOS5 for an universal application (iOS6 is OK)

Tags: ios, xcode, landscape

I'm using the Master-detail template in xcode4.5.1 to create an universal app. 
To keep landscape in iPad, I have following settings. It works in iOS6, but always keep portrait in iOS5. How can I solve the issue?  ( project linkage: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wm9l8kxhan6kp1/itstest.zip）

1. plist

   ```
   <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>

   <array>
   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>

   </array>

   <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>

   <array>
   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>

   </array>
   ```
2. even add following in Appdelegate.m

   ```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
   }
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` does not get called in your AppDelegate, only in your View Controllers ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a)). Place the following code inside your view controllers (Although for your particular project I think it would be enough to place it only inside your `MasterViewController`):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Add to both master and detail view controllers are necessary.